# How to translate the key fingerprint in an ssh log entry to the corresponding authorized_key?

Tags: ssh

I am enforcing the use of ssh keys as standard practice for administration on our organization's linux systems. This includes a particular account that serves as a tech support account without having full on root privileges that has the public keys of everyone who's allowed to access them in its `authorized_keys` file.

However, during a recent check of logging it turns out that the format of the fingerprint that `ssh` uses to report a successful login to the journal or syslog does not match the fingerprint as it's recorded in the `authorized_keys` file:

```
Apr 26 12:34:28 proteus sshd[44277]: Accepted publickey for adminuser from a.b.c.d port 54674 
ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:e1rz**REDACTED**8EZIY
```

The pertinent `authorized_keys` entry:

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3Nz**REDACTED**PfrMZ Shadur
```

(The log entry *does* match the result of `ssh-add -l` for the matching key).

How do I compare the key in the log to the entries in `authorized_keys` to verify which key was used to log in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate the fingerprint of a key with `echo $PUBLIC_KEY | ssh-keygen -l -f -`. Or for all authorized keys, simply `ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Then use those fingerprints for matching the log entries.